# hello friends. i created BottomNavigationBar like below, but i wnat to create a top Navigation bar like bottom how i will do that?

Tags: flutter

i created BottomNavigationBar like below, but i wnat to create a top Navigation bar like bottom how i will do that?

here is my code to create a bottonNavigationBar but i want to create a TOPNavigationBar

```
bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
       currentIndex: getpageindex,
       backgroundColor: Colors.black,
       onTap: onTabchangePage,
       activeColor: Colors.green,
       inactiveColor: Colors.white10,
       items: [
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.home)),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.search)),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.photo_camera,size: 40,)),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.notifications)),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_sharp)),
       ],
     ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `bottomNavigationBar` place the `CupertinoTabBar` in child of your body.

here is an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8vPWiFcWWQ